# Understanding angular/typescript setter property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I created the following Angular 2 directive:

```
import { Directive , Input , ViewContainerRef , TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUnless]'
})
export class UnlessDirective {

  @Input() set appUnless(condition : boolean) {
    if(!condition) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
    } else {
      this.vcRef.clear();      
    }
  }

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any> , private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

and i am using it in my main angular html file like so:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <p *appUnless="onlyOdd">UNLESS !!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
    </div>
```

I am not quite understanding how the below code works:

```
@Input() set appUnless(condition : boolean) {
        if(!condition) {
          this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
        } else {
          this.vcRef.clear();      
        }
      }
```

what exactly is `appUnless` , is it a property or a function or what exactly is it ?

Answer (score 1):

`appUnless` is a function that can be used like a property.
This way you can create a property with additional behavior when a values is set or read.
That's all the getter and setter stuff is about.